# How can I save and load the alpha values of a UIButton in an app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uibutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I save a UIButton's properties and load with a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338218/how-would-i-save-a-uibuttons-properties-and-load-with-a-button)

I am trying to save the values of "alpha" in 6 UIButtons in my app. How can I save the states when a button is pressed and load them when another button is pressed?

I am fairly new to this saving and loading so what would be the easiest way of doing this?

Searched everywhere and nothing seems to work...

Comment: You mean you want to save the "alpha" (transparency) value from the button's background color RGBA values?

Comment: What is it you really are trying to accomplish?  Saving just the alpha and not the complete color doesn't make much sense.  Do your buttons vary in transparency or something?

Comment: Also, if you can provide a relevent excerpt of the code that you tried and tell us what didn't work that would help.

Comment: The other question is already closed as a duplicate of this one, so we might as well leave this one open.  Trying to cast another close vote fails anyway, as it would be a circular reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand what you're trying to do, but here is how you would extract the alpha component of a button's background color and save it (I haven't compiled this but this should be close):

```
// get the alpha value from the CGColor components from the button's backgroundColor
UIColor* color = button.backgroundColor;
const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
CGFloat alpha = components[CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color.CGColor)-1];
```

Now you can use setFloat:forKey: to save the value to the NSUserDefaults:

```
// save alpha value (0.0=transparent to 1.0=opaque)
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setFloat:alpha forKey:@"buttonColorKey"];   // use your own key string
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003764) to store and load the alpha values.

Comment: How can I do this? I have followed many instructions but none have actually worked. Would you be able to provide a bit of sample code? Thanks!