# How would I save a UIButton's properties and load with a button?

Tags: ios, xcode, load, uibutton, save

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I save and load the alpha values of a UIButton in an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336594/how-can-i-save-and-load-the-alpha-values-of-a-uibutton-in-an-app)

I would like to save the state of the UIButton (e.g. its alpha value and whether it is hidden or not) and this would then load up when the user quits and reloads the app.

I've tried some bits of code with NSUserDefaults but with no luck.

Could somebody help with some sample code so that I can save and load the button's state?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to **Shaharyar**'s answer (i don't know how to comment):

in this case you need to use NSNumber.

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:SOME_FLOAT] forKey:KEY];`

because `float` is not an object, but `NSNumber` is one.

EDITED:

1) To make sure your defaults are created after the application runs at first time:
in your AppDelegate's `initialize`-method:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults  = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithFloat:SOME_FLOAT], @"YOUR_KEY", 
                             nil];
[defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
```

2) Updating defaults after:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setFloat:FLOAT_VALUE forKey:@"YOUR_KEY"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

3) Read defaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
float FLOAT_VALUE = [prefs floatForKey:@"YOUR_KEY"];
```

Comment: yes, but I don't want to set the alpha to one, I want it to automatically pick the info up from examplebutton.alpha as it may be different.

Comment: sorry, but i didn't really understand what do you mean. You can simply store the value of alfa as NSNumber and then read this float-value. And do not forget to register your defaults first

Answer (score 1):

Can you post some of the code?

`NSUserDefaults` is the place to store such information..

Assumption:

Did you make a call to `[NSUserDefaults synchronize]` after setting the values?

---

Code:

```
// Setting a value
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:VALUE forKey:KEY];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

// Getting a value
NSString *var1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:KEY];
```

---

In your case it would be:

```
// Setting a value
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:VALUE forKey:KEY];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: I did use [alphadefaults synchronize]. Here's some code I used: http://pastie.org/2498420. When I put this code in, the button just didn't show at all... I tried adding cross1.alpha = 0.3; on viewDidLoad, but didn't make a difference...

Comment: I put in; [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:cross1.alpha forKey:@"Cross1Alpha"]; but it said; Semantic Issue: Sending 'CGFloat' (aka 'float') to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

Comment: `setValue` requires you to send a reference of type ID (an actual object) - I just tried setting the alpha property myself 0.3 worked fine. It seems like your view object isn't initialized properly..

Comment: So what do I need to do my end now?